# Query sql for truncate post_content in wp_posts table

Tags: mysql, sql

Hello all i need remove all info in Wordpress posts content and i'ld like do it from phpmyadmin with a query.

I need remove only the text and images from all posts content but not the entire post, so i need know the sql query for do it, please someone can help me?
Stew

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Backup your db
2. Remeber to backup your db
3. Import the backup in another database, change wp-config.php to use this new database and see if everithing is ok. (Importing is successfull? Site appear without any change?)
4. Wordpress uses a prefix for table names. The default is 'wp_' but clever guys change it with something else. (The change is made in wp-config.php before install WP). So in my query I will use 'wp_' as table prefix, replace it with your table prefix if it's different.
5. In the new db (the one created from backup) run this query (remember to change `wp_posts` if your tables has a different prefix):

   ```
   UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = "", post_excerpt = "" WHERE post_type = 'post' AND post_status <> 'inherit' AND post_status <> 'trash';
   ```
6. Check your site and if anything goes wrong change `wp-config.php` to use the original db and then investigate the problem.

Comment: seem your query move all post in trash? are you sure it's correct

Comment: In trash? absolutely not. It doesn't truncate post in trash and revision posts. If you want truncate even them, use only `UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = "", post_excerpt = "" WHERE post_type = 'post'` @Stew